# How did the differentiation with respect to the vectors done here?

Tags: differentiation, calculus

[image: differentiation by vectorthis is the calculation for the virial of two particles]
A system of particles interacting through a two-body potential $u(\vec r_j-\vec r_i) $. Assuming the interparticle potential to be central and denoting it by the symbol $u(r) $, where $r=|\vec r_j-\vec r_i|$, the contribution arising from the pair of particles $i$ and $j$, with position vectors $\vec r_i$ and $\vec r_j$, is given by  $\vec r_i \cdot \left (-\frac {\partial u(r) }{\partial \vec r_i}\right)+\vec r_j \cdot \left (-\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial \vec r_j}\right)$
$=-\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r^2} \left (\vec r_i \cdot \frac{\partial |\vec r_j-\vec r_i|^2}{\partial \vec r_i}+\vec r_j \cdot \frac{\partial |\vec r_j-\vec r_i|^2}{\partial \vec r_j}\right)$
$=-r\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}$

Now how does the differentiation result in $\left(-r\frac {\partial u(r) }{\partial r}\right) $ ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Also, please be more specific *what* you want people to explain here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the  derivatives in the formula (15) are gradients. A gradient acts on a scalar function $\varphi = \varphi(x,y,z)$ in the following way:

$$grad \varphi \equiv \nabla \varphi = \left(\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}\right)$$

The result of a gradient is always a vector. This vector has the direction of the steepest increase of value of $\varphi$.

So for instance if $\varphi = | \mathbf{r}_i -\mathbf{r}_j|^2$

$$\frac{\partial  | \mathbf{r}_i -\mathbf{r}_j|^2}{\partial \mathbf{r}_i} = grad_{\mathbf{r}_i} [(x_i -x_j)^2 + (y_i-y_j)^2 + (z_i- z_j)^2 ]= \left( \frac{\partial ((x_i -x_j)^2 + (y_i-y_j)^2 + (z_i- z_j)^2)}{\partial x_i}, \frac{\partial ((x_i -x_j)^2 + (y_i-y_j)^2 + (z_i- z_j)^2)}{\partial y_i}, \frac{\partial ((x_i -x_j)^2 + (y_i-y_j)^2 + (z_i- z_j)^2)}{\partial z_i}\right)$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{\partial  | \mathbf{r}_i -\mathbf{r}_j|^2}{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}= \left( 2 (x_i-x_j), 2 (y_i - y_j), 2 ( z_i- z_j)\right) = 2(\mathbf{r_i - r_j})$$

If there is a derivative $\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbf{r}_j}$ the same operation has to be carried out, the partial derivatives are to be done with $x_j, y_j$ and $z_j$.

By the way, the derivative $\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}$ is not a gradient, it is a simple 1-dimensional derivative.

In formula (15) the chain rule was applied (k = i or k= j):

$$-\mathbf{r}_k \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial \mathbf{r}_k }   = -\mathbf{r}_k \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r^2 }\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial \mathbf{r}_k} = -\mathbf{r}_k \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r^2 }\frac{\partial  | \mathbf{r}_i -\mathbf{r}_j|^2}{\partial \mathbf{r}_k}$$

The expression inside the brackets becomes:

$${ \ldots  } = 2 [\mathbf{r}_i (\mathbf{r_i-r_j}) + \mathbf{r}_j(\mathbf{r_j- r_i})] = 2 |\mathbf{r}_i -\mathbf{r}_j|^2 = 2r^2 $$

And finally

$$\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r^2} = \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}\frac{\partial \sqrt{r^2}}{\partial r^2} = \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{r^2}}$$

Put together one gets:

$$-\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r^2}[ \ldots ] =-\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{r^2}}\cdot 2 r^2  = -\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r} r$$

Comment: Ya right...I was taking the dots as dot product ....Thank you so much

Comment: @Manisha it is a scalar product of 2 vectors because $\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial\mathbf{r}_k}$ is a vector as well as $\frac{\partial |\mathbf{r_i - r_j}|^2}{\partial\mathbf{r}_k}$.